# Writing specific bytes in T-SQL binary datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to insert data currently saved as `tinyint` values of a column into a single `binary(n)` value in order specified by a different column. (Kind of imitating a byte array of sorts, I suppose.)

If this was strings being joined into a larger string, I'd do it something like this:

```
declare @string table (str varchar(100), ord int)
insert into @string
select 'A', 1
union all
select 'B', 3
union all
select 'C', 2

declare @strings varchar(1000)
set @strings = ''
select @strings = @strings + str
from @string
order by ord

select @string --would return ACB
```

This, obviously, is not the right way for the `binary` datatype (what with no empty variable option being available and addition not working that way for `binary`), but is there any similar way of doing this?

Comment: It's not even (necessarily) reliable for [strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484.aspx): "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each output row."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, as long as my assumptions are correct

- that you want each `tinyint` to be one byte in the final result.
- that we aren't dealing with too much data - the intermediate results might use up quite a bit of space
- that each `ord` value exists from 1 - some maximum value, with no gaps.

Here:

```
declare @t table (s tinyint not null,ord int not null)
insert into @t(s,ord) values (12,1),(1,2),(255,3)

;With Cat as (
    select CONVERT(varbinary(max),s) as run,ord
    from @t where ord = 1
    union all
    select run + CONVERT(varbinary(1),s),t.ord
    from Cat c inner join @t t on c.ord = t.ord - 1
)
select run from Cat where ord = (select MAX(ord) from @t)
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Result:

```
0x0C01FF
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FOR XML PATH`:

```
select c, convert(varbinary, c)
from (
    select str as [text()]
    from @string
    order by ord
    for xml path('')
) x(c)
```